# How can I use estimated probabilities of a class from rpart to identify the top N classes?

Tags: r, classification, cart, rpart

Using the `rpart` library, I'm trying to predict which class each observation belongs to. Here is a reproducible example explaining the steps I am taking:

```
library(rpart)

# training set
df_train <- data.frame(
  tag = c('123', '123', '124', '124', '125'),
  p1 = c('home', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'home'),
  p2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
)

# testing set
df_test <- data.frame(
  tag = c('123', '124', '125'),
  p1 = c('home', 'work', 'home'),
  p2 = c(1, 1, 0)
)

# train model
model.rpart = rpart(tag~p1+p2, data=df_train, method="class")

# predict probabilities of class
pred.rpart = predict(model.rpart, data=df_test, method="prob")

# list out results
pred.rpart
```

My problem is that I don't fully understand the output of the table `pred.rpart`

```
> pred.rpart
  123 124 125
1 0.4 0.4 0.2
2 0.4 0.4 0.2
3 0.4 0.4 0.2
4 0.4 0.4 0.2
5 0.4 0.4 0.2
```

I thought it was giving me a list of probabilities for each class in my test dataset, but I don't understand why there are five rows, when I am just trying to look at the predictions of the test data set.

**Why does `pred.rpart` contain five rows of data?**

My overall objective is to find the top N predictions for a class. So for the first observation in my `df_test` dataframe, I would like to be able to say:

```
Top 2 predictions for the first observation:
  #1: '123': 40%
  #2: '124': 40%
```

Once I understand the output of `rpart.pred` I want to summarize this using the following command to give me each class prediction, ordered by probability:

```
n_classes <- 2
apply(pred.rpart,1,function(xx)head(names(sort(xx, decreasing=T)), n_classes))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is almost correct.    You are getting five rows because you are getting the predictions for `df_train`.  Note that you get the same answer if you simply omit `data=df_test`.   The problem is that you wrote 
`data=df_test`,  but `predict` wants the argument `newdata=df_test`.  Take a look at the help page `?predict.rpart`  or even just 
`args(rpart:::predict.rpart)`.

Comment: Interesting point. And very bad choice of param names in the function I would say. It is almost a bug!

Comment: @Picarus I agree as using `data=df` does not throw an error